# unir varios json en un solo archivo en python

Tags: python-3.x, json

tengo varios archivos JSON que leo en Python, y me gustaría unirlos en uno solo.

```
ar_1 = pd.read_json('01.json', lines = True)
ar_2 = pd.read_json('02.json', lines = True)
ar_3 = pd.read_json('03.json', lines = True)
```

No se que es más eficiente a nivel computacional si "concat" o "append"

Gracias de antemano y un saludo